# A program that counts the number of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to create a program that counts the number of times each digit (ranging from 0 to 9) occurs, using functions and arrays. Here are the instructions I am given:

Write a program that asks the user to enter an NxM-dimensional array containing only the digits between 0 and 9 and counts the number of times each one of the 10 digits appears in the array.

This program should:

● prompt a user to enter the sizes (rows and columns) of the array, and read in the dimensions

● prompt the user to enter the array row-by-row and read in each row and verify that the user has entered values between 0 and 9. If values outside of this range are entered, the program should prompt the user to enter the row again

● display the total number of times each digit appears in the array

The output of the program should look like this (in case if this helps):
This program counts occurrences of digits 0 through 9 in an NxM array

*Enter the size of your array: 2 6

*Enter row 0: 0 1 2 3 4 5

*Enter row 1: 0 1 6 72 81 9

Values outside of range.

*Enter row 1: 0 1 6 7 8 9

Total count for each digit:

Digit 0 occurs 2 times

Digit 1 occurs 2 times

Digit 2 occurs 1 time

Digit 3 occurs 1 time

Digit 4 occurs 1 time

Digit 5 occurs 1 time

Digit 6 occurs 1 time

Digit 7 occurs 1 time

Digit 8 occurs 1 time

Digit 9 occurs 1 time

*User's input

Here is my program so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int read_row(int x, int y, int a[x][y]) /*function read_row reads in each row (including the prompt and retrieving the values). */
{
    printf("Enter the size of your array:");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
    a[x][y] = 10;    // x is the row count while y is the number of digits inputted
    while (x < 10 && y < 10)
    {
        printf("Enter row %d:", x);
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}

bool check_input(int x, int y) /*function check_input verifies that the user has not entered values outside the range 0 through 9. The function returns true if the range is ok and false otherwise. */

{
    if (x > 9)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    if (y > 9)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}

int compute_row_count(int x, int y, int a[x][y], int count) /*function compute_row_count counts the number of time each digit occurs in an individual row. */
{
   a[x][y] = 0;
   for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            while (y > 0)
            {
                count = y % 10;    // count reads and calculates the number of times a digit occurs in each row
                y /= 10;
            }
            a[y] = y;
        }


    }  
    return a[x][y];
}

int print_total_count(int x, int y, int a[x][y], int count) /*function print_total_count prints out the total count for each digit. Note the difference between printing “1 time” and “2 times”. */
{
    printf("Total count for each digit:\n");
    a[x][y] = 10;
        for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                if (count <= 1)
                    printf("Digit %d occurs %d time\n", y, count);
                if(count >= 2 && y < 10)
                    printf("Digit %d occurs %d times\n", y, count);
            }
        return (y, count);
}

int main (void) /* I mainly need help on compute_row_total and print_total_count. Once I can figure those two out, I should be able to set this part up correctly, so no need to worry about this part */
{
int x, y, a[x][y], count;

read_row(x, y, a[x][y]);
if (check_input(x,y))
    printf("Values are outside of range.");
else 
    break;
compute_row_count(x, y, a[x][y], count);
print_total_count(x, y, a[x][y], count);


return 0;
}
```

I left my compute_row_count function sort of empty because I do not understand if I am missing any other calculations or have inaccurate ones...once I finalize compute_row_count and print_total_count, I should be able to finish the int main(void) from there. (So no need to worry about helping me at this part). However, I do need serious help with compute and print_total...so please help me.

Comment: There are too many problems in your code. Did your compiler not report any errors?

Comment: I do see errors like "expected ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(y)]’ but argument is of type ‘int’" and "passing argument 3 of ‘compute_row_count’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"...but I am not using pointers? I'm sorry, but I do not clearly understand these errors...

Comment: I think this question is too broad for SO.  I don't mean to be impolite, but your code suggests that you really don't understand how 2D arrays work in C (along with several other aspects of C programming), and an SO post is not the place to teach you this concept from scratch.  I think all I can advise is spending more time with your textbook and/or instructor.

Comment: input `x,y` at main. use `check_input` inside of `read_row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static inline bool check_input(int n){
    return 0 <= n && n <= 9;
}

void read_row(int x, int y, int a[x][y]){
    for (int r = 0; r < x; ++r){
        printf("Enter row %d: ", r);
        for (int c = 0; c < y; ++c){
            int value;
            if(1 != scanf("%d", &value) || check_input(value) == false){
                printf("Values outside of range.\n");
                while(getchar() != '\n'); //clear inputs;
                --r;
                break;
            }
            a[r][c] = value;
        }
    }
}

void compute_row_count(int x, int y, int a[x][y], int counts[]){
    //memset(counts, 0, sizeof(int)*10);
    for (int r = 0; r < x; ++r){
        for (int c = 0; c < y; ++c){
            ++counts[a[r][c]];
        }
    }
}

void print_total_count(int counts[]){
    printf("\nTotal count for each digit:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        printf("Digit %d occurs %d time%s\n", i, counts[i], counts[i] > 1 ? "s": "");
    }
}

int main (void){
    int x, y;
    printf("Enter the size of your array: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    int a[x][y];
    int counts[10] = {0};

    read_row(x, y, a);
    compute_row_count(x, y, a, counts);
    print_total_count(counts);

    return 0;
}
```